# Chinese database content within dynamic PHP pages using CodeIgniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm trying to pull Chinese database content to some dynamic PHP pages within our CodeIgniter website. The PHP files that make up each page are encoded as UTF-8 which displays static Chinese text correctly. However, all Chinese content from the database is rendered as question marks.

For example `中华人民共和国` in the database shows up as `???????`.

As with the PHP code, all tables are collated as `utf8_unicode_ci`. The data shows correctly in the database. Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now sorted. Line 50 of `database.php` in **root -> application -> config** should have read:

Correct:
`$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8"`

Incorrect:
`$db['default']['char_set'] = "UTF-8"`

Something so simple! I hope that might help others.